# DevOps multiple projects with multiple stage deployments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have 10 projects in devops and each project has 10 stages one for each environment (env1-env10).

If I create a release in project1, I can select all 10 environments and the application will be released to them all. But, if I want to deploy all projects to environment 7, I have to go into each project and create a release just for that environment. Is there a way I can create a release pipeline that will call the release pipeline with just that stage set to deploy all 10 projects to just the 1 environment (i.e. if I pick env7 then it will only create a release for that stage in each project)?

I tried to set up a pipeline in each project but I can't work out how to set up 1 pipeline that isn't related to just 1 individual project

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

There’s an extension  `Release Orchestrator` that can trigger one or multiple pipelines across projects to orchestrate build and deployment of application components in a specific order.
You can get it from Visual Studio Marketplace.URL:[Release Orchestrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dmitryserbin.release-orchestrator)
For example:

```
 Project name: Target project name  
 Definition name  :  Target release definition name
 Definition stage: Target release’s env you want to deploy to
```

[image: release]

[image: variables]

[image: history]

Comment: @feijoc2 Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.